# execute commands on remote host in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

i am trying to ssh into a remote host and then execute certain commands on the remote host's shell. Following is my pipeline code.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        // comment added
         APPLICATION = 'app'
         ENVIRONMENT = 'dev'
         MAINTAINER_NAME = 'jenkins'
         MAINTAINER_EMAIL = 'jenkins@email.com'
    }
    stages {
         stage('clone repository') {
             steps {
                 // cloning repo
                 checkout scm
             }
         }
         stage('Build Image') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     sshagent(credentials : ['jenkins-pem']) {
                        sh "echo pwd"
                        sh 'ssh -t -t ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
                        sh "echo pwd"
                        sh 'sudo -i -u root'
                        sh 'cd /opt/docker/web'
                        sh 'echo pwd'
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

But upon running this job it executes `sh 'ssh -t -t ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'` successfully but it stops there and does not execute any further commands. I want to execute the commands that are written after `ssh` command inside the remote host's shell. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Jenkins executes sh and the  returns. This means the ssh command is run to the remote, but the next echo pwd is run localy

Comment: @Prikkeldraad is there a way to run commands on remote shell in jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 11):

I resolve this issue

```
script 
{
    sh """ssh -tt login@host << EOF 
    your command
    exit
    EOF"""
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I would try something like this:

```
sshagent(credentials : ['jenkins-pem']) {
  sh "echo pwd"
  sh 'ssh -t -t ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "echo pwd && sudo -i -u root && cd /opt/docker/web && echo pwd"'
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer but it is still not working. it is not even executing the ssh command.

Comment: The answer that I was looking for, a solution that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
    stage("DEPLOY CONTAINER"){
        steps {
            script {
                    sh """
                    #!/bin/bash
                    sudo ssh -i /path/path/keyname.pem username@serverip << EOF
                    sudo bash /opt/filename.sh
                    exit 0
                    << EOF
                    """
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the reason for #!/bin/bash before ssh command? and sudo ssh ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to run commands on remote using SSH. I know this is late answer but I just explored this thing so would like to share and this will help others to resolve this problem easily.

I just found [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osx-bsd-ssh-run-command-on-remote-machine-server/) helpful on how to run multiple commands on remote using SSH. Also we can run multiple commands conditionally as mentioned in above blog.
By going through it, I found the syntax:

`ssh username@hostname "command1; command2;commandN"`

Now, how to run command inside remote hots using SSH in Jenkins pipeline?

Here is the solution:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    /*
     define your command in variable
     */
    remoteCommands =
      """java --version;
    java --version;
    java --version """
  }
  stages {
    stage('Login to remote host') {
      steps {
        sshagent(['ubnt-creds']) {
          /*
              Provide variable as argument in ssh command
          */
          sh 'ssh -tt username@hostanem $remoteCommands'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly and optionally, you can define a variable that holds all commands separated by `;(semicolon)`  and then pass it as parameter in command.

Another way, you can also pass your commands directly to ssh command as

`sh "ssh -tt username@hostanem 'command1;command2;commandN'"`

I have used it in my code and it's working great!
[see the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV5QR.png)

Happy Learning :)